# Openssl library is not loaded at Mac M1 (Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib)

Tags: python, openssl, homebrew, pymssql, apple-m1

Can someone help me please?
I'm trying to run at my Mac a Python automation tests using `PyTest` in my `venv` environment but having such an error:

> Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib

I've tried to reinstall openssl:

```
brew reinstall openssl@1.1
..........

A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in   /opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/certs

and run   /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/c_rehash

openssl@1.1 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew, because macOS provides LibreSSL.

If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH, run:   echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:   export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"   export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
```

I did what was suggested above:

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc 
source ~/.zshrc 
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib" 
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include" 

echo $PATH 
/Users/danylokholodov/Documents/my-project/Core_Platform/Code/my-project-qa-framework/venv/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands

which openssl 
/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/openssl
```

But still have the same error during executing tests:

```
../../../venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymssql/__init__.py:3: in <module>
    from ._pymssql import *
E   ImportError: dlopen(/Users/danylokholodov/Documents/my-project/Core_Platform/Code/my-project-qa-framework/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymssql/_pymssql.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
E     Referenced from: /Users/danylokholodov/Documents/my-project/Core_Platform/Code/my-project-qa-framework/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymssql/_pymssql.cpython-39-darwin.so
E     Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution on my M1 was [@Bhupendra singh negi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13003793/bhupendra-singh-negi) 's but with the correct version concerned

```bash
brew reinstall openssl@1.1

echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it installing Anaconda, then I created a ENV with Conda Environment and Python 3.8 (in my case was python 3.8 because 3.9 isn't working with Psycopg2). then I downloaded Pymssql from Anaconda->Environments->not installed. Then i went to the python interpreter on pycharm preferences and I selected the anaconda little logo, then + and I installed manually pymssql on the ENV.

Answer (score 0):

This worked on my M1

> brew install openssl

> echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

> source ~/.zshrc